# Eloquent laravel models empty id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with inserting order details about order.

Models:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','name','surname','fathers_name','phone_number','city','post_office','comment'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function orderDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetails');
    }

}
```

---

```
class OrderDetails extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['order_id','product_id','amount'];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');

    }


}
```

Tables:

Orders:
id
user_id
p_number
city
status
...

Order_details:
id
order_id
prod_id
amount
...

Controller:

```
$data = $request->except('_token','submit');
```

**$order = new Order();
    $order->create($data);**

```
    $order_details = new OrderDetails();

    $cart_content = Cart::content();
    $order_content = [];



    foreach($cart_content as $key=>$cart_item) {
        $order_content[$key]['order_id'] = $order->id;
        $order_content[$key]['id'] = $cart_item->id;
        $order_content[$key]['qty'] = $cart_item->qty;
        $order_content[$key]['price'] = $cart_item->price;
    }

    dd($order_content);

        /*
    foreach($order_content as $order_item)
    {
        $order_details->create($order_item);

    }

        */
```

So when I print $order_content, im getting 'order_id' null, how should I properly get id of order to fill its field in order_details?

In the end i should get something like this:

```
Orders:
1
1
+12345678
NY
processing
...

Order_details:
1
1
2
5
-----------
2
1
3
4
-----------
3
1
8
2
-----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save result to a variable:

```
$order = (new Order)->create($data);
```

Or:

```
$order = Order::create($data);
```

Comment: @Batmannn no, you're doing `$order = new Order(); $order->create($data);` Your code will return an empty model after `create()`. And the code from my answer will return created model. And as I said in your another question, your architecture is not good. You should learn about many-to-many relationship and use it for `Order` and `Product` models and get rid of `OrderDetails` model.